# Separate between numbers

Tags: c

I made this coding but I couldn't complete. The idea is should enter numbers and on the screen must shown as separately. Ex) If we enter:1234  result: 1 2 3 4.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int show_digit(int x);
int main(void)
{
    int x;
    printf("Enter the variable:");
    scanf("%d", &x);
    printf("%d ", show_digit(x));
    return 0;
}
int show_digit(int x)
{
        return show_digit(x / 10)%10;
}
```

Comment: That's just matter of algorithm!

Comment: OK who is downvoting everybody?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen You're the last woman/man standing. :-)

Comment: @cad I'm a dude.  Seems everyone posted too quickly and/or stole their answers from other SO posts.  Naughty, naughty!

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen SO is not Facebook (which has only "like" button)

Answer (score 2):

You seemed to be trying to make `show_digit()` recursive, but you got stuck on how to actually do it.  This refactored version of your function actually traverses from the *last* digit of the input to the *first* (which is the base case), and then starts printing out spaced digits as it comes out of the recursion.  Note that I changed the return type of `show_digits()` to `void` because it is really now a utility function which does not compute anything.

```
void show_digit(int x)
{
    if (x < 10)
    {
        printf("%d ", x);
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        show_digit(x/10);
    }

    int the_digit = x % 10;
    printf("%d ", the_digit);

    return;
}
```

Comment: See your `return;`, and also see return type of `show_digit`, it should be `void`

Comment: @DMaster Because I changed the signature of the `show_digit()` method in the OP I feel that maybe it is justified to show how it should be used in the `main()` method.  If you disagree, state your reason and I will remove this extra code.

Comment: Because I think the answer should be short, it makes ease of read and understand. Also, @AbdulazizMukhamedov is a human, not a machine, he should know how to update his `main` function without knowing your `main` function.

Answer (score 0):

In this answer, I will not show you any code, but I will explain what's your issue.

I tried to compile your code, it compile successfully, but when I run it, the program crashed, is that your issue?

I know why your program crashed: *Out of memory!*

How did it happen?

Your function `int show_digit(int)` is a recursive function, in this function, you didn't made a statement to stop recursion, so, the recursion will continue until the function's stack reach maximum size of allowed memory, then it finally causes crashing.

Answer (score -1):

Non-recursive version:

```
int digits[256];
int i = 0;
    do {
       digits[i++]=x%10;
       x /= 10;
    } while (x);

for (i=i-1; i>=0; i--) {
   printf ("%d ", digits[i]);
}
```

It will work fine for positive integers.